# Why did stackoverflow decide to put the answer box at the bottom of all the answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, answers

On pages that have a long thread of answers I am interested to know why the answer box (for answering questions) is at the bottom of the thread of answers?

Why not put this somewhere else on the page? Was there a specific reason to put it at the bottom below all the answers?

---

Update: Just to be clear, I'm not trying say it should be changed or say that it was a bad decision, I'm just interested to know the reasoning behind the decision or if there is any empirical evidence for the decision.

Comment: I can't speak at to the exact reasons, but shouldn't you read the other answers before adding another (possible duplicate) one?

Comment: Ready to answer?  Just press `End` and start typing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You spend hours and hours hacking away at something, you have no hair left to pull out of your head, so you go to google one more time and type "how do I move the bleeping frog?" You see a link to a question on StackOverflow about moving the frog and you click on it.

What's more useful to you? Seeing the question and a box for you to enter your own answer? *You don't have an answer! The bleeping frog is laughing at you!* Or is it seeing that some other person has mastered the art of frog-movement and has graciously provided the method to allow you to do the same?

Answer (score 25):

In my opinion, the answer box *should* be at the bottom of the answers since it forces an answerer to scroll past answers that are already given. They *should* read through the answers already there *before* they post their own, in order to avoid adding useless duplicated content.

Comment: +1 Like I was about to do when you posted this.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to make sense that box would be at the bottom.  It would not fit on the side bar and for most of the uses of the page (people coming there for the answer to the question) the answers are more important, as is the question.

Comment: Useful as in making it quicker for people who don't read other answers before posting a same same answer?

Comment: ...which is not useful.  This answer is also not useful, -1.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph.  For a good 90% of visitors the answer box would just be in the way.

Comment: Good point that option would be a bad idea, removed.